# Is it possible to modify the number of the output layer of a Tensorflow model ( frozen graph model )?

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

I'm trying to use a pre-trained model that detects 68 key points of the face to detect only the eye region ( 80 key points )

Training a model from scratch doesn't give a good prediction, for that reason I search for a way to modify the output layer of the frozen graph model (logits/BiasAdd:0) from 68 to 40 key points.

Updates:
That was the pretrained model, I would like to change 136 ( 68 * 2) to 80 (40*2) as mentioned in the image below

How can I do that?

[image]

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: search for tf transfer knowledge and fine tuning

Comment: More explanation, please.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

Comment: Example and code provided in this article don't meet to my object. I search for another solution, I think that you did not understand me.